# commandlink disabled still triggers the action

Tags: jsf, commandlink

I have a custom tag in which I use a commandLink tag. The problem is that in some cases I want the action that happens in the back not to happen, actually to disable the link, but in some cases I want the link to work.

```
<p:commandLink action="#{bean.doSomething(param)}" styleClass="line" disabled="#{disable}"> 
    <div> bla </div> 
</p:commandLink>
```

In this example 'disable' is a boolean parameter that I receive from the outside of the custom tag. How can I block the action for commandLink based on a boolean parameter or any other method?

Comment: Have you tried to hardcode `disabled="#{true}"` just to see if this is a variable problem?

Comment: disabled is a boolean flag.

Comment: Thanks Alexandre, it eventually worked hardcoded.